# fsutil usn for mounted volumes without drive letter

Tags: windows, mounted-volumes, fsutil, usn

I've a volume mounted at E:\mnt path.
On querying `fsutil usn queryjournal E:\mnt` it works fine. But when I run `fsutil usn readJournal E:\mnt` it gives `Error:  Access is denied.`

How can I resolve this?

`fsutil usn queryjournal E:\mnt`

```
Usn Journal ID   : 0x01da13bddee65729
First Usn        : 0x0000000000000000
Next Usn         : 0x00000000000b40f0
Lowest Valid Usn : 0x0000000000000000
Max Usn          : 0x00000fffffff0000
Maximum Size     : 0x0000000008000000 (128.0 MB)
Allocation Delta : 0x0000000000800000 (  8.0 MB)
Minimum record version supported : 2
Maximum record version supported : 4
Write range tracking: Enabled
Write range tracking chunk size: 16384
Write range tracking file size threshold: 1048576
```

`fsutil usn readJournal E:\mnt startUsn=0x00000000000b40f0`

`Error:  Access is denied.`